# how to disable click method on nested div element

Tags: html, angular

```html
<div class="param_content" (click)="onParamClick()">
  <div class="heading-warning">
    <div>{{ _paDetail.name }}</div>
    <div>
      <img src="assets/att-im.svg" (click)="showInfo()">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In above code, when I click on image line 5 and expected to invoke `showInfo()` method but along with this `onParamClick()` method is also executing.
How to disable `onParamClick()` method on image click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass the event into the parameter for the function

```
(click)="showInfo($event)"


function showInfo(e)
{
//your code
e.stopPropagation();
}
```

inside the showInfo function

refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: I'm using angular, could you please let me know how to use it? Thanks

Comment: hope this link will help you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-stoppropagation-v53xfx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html